# Selecting rows from a pandas DataFrame: only rows with at least three ones need to be selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing some 25000 rows. This is what the data looks like. I want to select only the rows with which have at least three 1s the columns cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4.

```py
import pandas as pd
ds = {'gene': ['as01', 'as02', 'as03', 'as04', 'as05'], 
        'tf': ['tf1', 'tf2', 'tf3', 'tf4', 'tf5'], 
     'cond1': ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1'], 
     'cond2': ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0'], 
     'cond3': ['0', '0', 'NaN', '0', '0'], 
     'cond4': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

print(df)
   gene   tf cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4
0  as01  tf1     0     1     0     1
1  as02  tf2     1     0     0     1
2  as03  tf3     0     1     NaN     1
3  as04  tf4     1     1     0     1
4  as05  tf5     1     0     0     0
```

I converted the NaN to 0, as it won't impact my downstream work and tried to select the rows by using the following line.  It did not work, I get an indexing error. I am not very experienced in using Python and having a hard time figuring it out.

```py
   gene   tf cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4
0  as01  tf1     0     1     0     1
1  as02  tf2     1     0     0     1
2  as03  tf3     0     1     0     1
3  as04  tf4     1     1     0     1
4  as05  tf5     1     0     0     0

df_new=df.loc[ df.iloc[:,3:6].sum() > 3 ]

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Can anybody suggest a solution to this? It would be great if there is a way to do this without having to convert the NaN to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `eq('1')` and change slicing to 2-6

```
df[df.iloc[:,2:6].eq('1').sum(1) >= 3]

Out[450]:
   gene   tf cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4
3  as04  tf4     1     1     0     1
```

Comment: @Anonymous: you are welcome. One up on your question, too +1. Happy coding :)

Comment: On another note, why is the column index 2:6 instead of being 2:5?

Comment: @Anonymous: `iloc` slicing is different from `loc` slicing. `iloc` slicing follows regular array slicing convention, it ignores the `stop`, so it must be `6` to pick `5`.

Comment: Thanks Andy, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can do the following:

```
mask = np.nansum(df.values[:, 2:6].astype(np.float), axis=1) >= 3

print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   gene   tf cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4
3  as04  tf4     1     1     0     1
```

The function [np.nansum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) will take care of converting the NaN to zero.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. Appreciate the help!